# Generate barcode liner and fill to picturebox

Tags: barcode

how to Generate barcode liner then fill to picturebox vb.net and then save barcode picture on pocture box to database sql server?

Comment: Why would you want to save the barcode image in the database? You can always recreate it from the encoded data.

Comment: If you are success in generating the image than there is also the way to save image formate in database